# Laptop exact ram slots

Tags: memory, motherboard, task-manager, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS K46CB with 6G ram (2G+4G). Today I bought a 4G ram and replaced the 2G. When I replaced I saw only 2 ram slots, but in ram profile tab of task manager, it says “slots used: 2 of 4”. Which one should I trust? I it possible that I missed some ram slots?

Comment: What does the service manual say?

Comment: I lost manual. but in it's site, It just mentioned number of current rams. and in mb site, It's not mentioned.

Comment: [The specifications are very clear.](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K46CB/specifications/)  " 2 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 8 GB SDRAM "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have only 2 RAM slots. Four are supported in hardware, but only two are wired to actual slots.

Answer (score 2):

The [user guide](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/K46CB/E_eManual_K46CB_VER7596.pdf) shows only two slots, see page 66.